# Squarify — How to adjust treemap rectangle shapes

Tags: python, matplotlib, squarify

I can't find a way in Squarify's documentation to edit the shapes of the rectangles inside the treeplot. I want to show one of the rectangles as a square subset of one of the other rectangles. This is what I have currently:

```
import squarify
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

treemap_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'names': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'sizes': [25, 50, 75]
})

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
ax = squarify.plot(
    treemap_df.sizes,
    label=treemap_df.names,
    color=["red","green","grey"],
    alpha=.8,
    edgecolor="white",
    linewidth=4
)

# I can get the coordinates of the squares/patches like this:
for rect in ax.patches:
    x, y, w, h = rect.get_x(), rect.get_y(), rect.get_width(), rect.get_height()
    c = rect.get_facecolor()
    print(f'Rectangle x={rect.get_x()} y={rect.get_y()} w={rect.get_width()} h={rect.get_height()} ')
    
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Basic Treemap')
plt.show()
```

This gives me the following output:

[image]

So, let's say that I just want to edit the plot so that rectangle 'A' is a square — is there a way I can do that? Ideally I'd like to be able to have shape 'B' not even be a square but to look like 'A' is an inset into rectangle 'B' (which would then have an L shape in its actual footprint), but just being able to tweak the rectange shape/locations at all would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach first loops through the rectangles and saves the positions of rectangles `A` and `B`.

Then, `A`'s width and height are modified to the square root of their product.

A new L-shaped polygon is created based on the coordinates of `A` and `B`, and copying the properties of `B`. Afterwards, `B` is removed.

Note that the following code only works for the specific positions of `A` and `B`. Other positions will need a bit different L-shape, or might be impossible.

Also note that for a square to look like a square, an equal aspect ratio is needed. Squarify uses parameters `norm_x` and `norm_y`, defaulting to `100`, which are the dimensions of the surrounding rectangle. You can change them to have a different aspect ratio, but be aware that this might change the positioning of the generated rectangles.

```py
import squarify
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from math import sqrt

names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
sizes = [25, 50, 75]

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = squarify.plot(
    sizes,
    norm_x=100,
    norm_y=100,
    label=names,
    color=["red", "green", "grey"],
    alpha=.8,
    edgecolor="white",
    linewidth=4)

for rect, name in zip(ax.patches, names):
    (x, y), w, h = rect.get_xy(), rect.get_width(), rect.get_height()
    c = rect.get_facecolor()
    print(f'Rectangle {name} x={rect.get_x()} y={rect.get_y()} w={rect.get_width()} h={rect.get_height()} ')
    if name == 'A':
        rect_for_square = rect
        sq_size = sqrt(w * h)
        xa, ya = x, y
    if name == 'B':
        rect_for_L = rect
        xb, yb, wb, hb = x, y, w, h

rect_for_square.set_width(sq_size)
rect_for_square.set_height(sq_size)
points = [[xb, ya + sq_size], [xb, yb + hb], [xb + wb, yb + hb], [xb + wb, ya],
          [xb + sq_size, ya], [xb + sq_size, ya + sq_size], [xb, ya + sq_size]]

poly_L = Polygon(points, closed=True)
poly_L.update_from(rect_for_L) # copy colors, alpha, linewidths, ...
ax.add_patch(poly_L)

rect_for_L.remove()

ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]